# How to convert a very old appengine .datastore to the new sqlite format?

Tags: google-app-engine

AppEngine SDK used a file based .datastore file previously

At the very beginning the appid's didn't internally have the "dev~" prefix, which caused issues for some people, this issues were solved with the --namespace argument of the old_dev_appserver

Yet the new dev_appserver doesn't include this namespace option, which locked the data to the old_dev_appserver, which is now removed from the SDK's

Answer (score 0):

First step is to use --port_sqlite --use_sqlite commands with the old_dev_appserver

The --datastore_path and --namespace= might also be need to set (--namespace= helps really old formats of .datastore's as they didn't have the "dev~" prefix)

Using these 4 options converts the data to an sqlite database, however the new dev_appserver doesn't have the namespace option, so the old data is unreachable

To solve this issue, one needs to modify the database by opening it with a program like "DB Browser for SQLite" - you will see the tables with appid's, without the "dev~" prefixes, just add the "dev~" prefixes to the table names and start the app using the new dev_appserver

---

After testing, I've found out that instead of re-factoring the .sqlite database itself, it's much easier to locate and override the application_configuration.py file of the SDK, setting partition's to '' and simplifying self._application to not include 'dev~' is enough